# Polymer dom-repeat item attributes not updating

Tags: javascript, dom, data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

Given this elements template:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{_getCatsToDisplay(requestedCats, catObj)}}">
  <div class="cat-item" title$="{{_getCatTitle(item)}}">
    <span>example</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am listening to changes in the element's life cycle on `attributeChanged` to update the `title` text for each `item` in the `dom-repeat`.

Ultimately the object is changing to have an updated title but the DOM is not reflecting the change unless I completely reinstantiate my custom element all together.

How can I make sure the DOM updates when the object or `item` in the `dom-repeat` is updated (in this case, the item's title attribute)?

Comment: Please include the code that shows how you "update the `title` text for each `item` in the `dom-repeat`".